How to extract Time Machine files from 2015-2018?
I have an external hard drive that I previously used for Time Machine backups. I'm at a loss because while some files of the backups have complete directories, others appear to be Zero kb.
For example, I have a structure similar to this:

Documents/
Sites/

In one backup from 2015, Sites/ is a full directory. Later that same year, it shows up as Zero kb (in Finder it appears as an alias, but I can't get it to tell me where it's actually linking to.)
Is there a way to properly "extract" everything from the backups that have weird symlinks/aliases? I realize now that Time Machine backups aren't proper backups, but I'm trying to salvage everything I possibly can from this older drive.
I have tried rsync (possibly with the wrong settings), and have tried to mess around with tmutil with little to no help. Is there something I'm missing?

The way TM works is that everything that is the same as the last backup is a link to the previous backup. The best way to restore files from a TM drive is with the TM application, or Migration Assistant.
